# How to display an image in the right top corner of another

Tags: javascript, css

I want to display an image in the right top corner of an another image using java script.

How can I implement that?

I have used the `appendChild()` method to add the image element to another, but it is not appending.

```
function appendImage(element, src, alt)   
{    
  var image = new Image();    
  image.src = src;    
  image.alt = alt;    
  element.appendChild(image);    
  return false;    
}

<img border="0" src="www.gravatar.com/avatar/" alt="" width="70" height="70"     
onclick="appendImage(this, 'cancel3.png', 'Picture of foo')";>
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: appendchild will not work in requirement, you can overlay images using position and z-index..  http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/Zd2VX/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can't "append an image to another." It is invalid HTML to put another element inside an image--since the `<img>` tag cannot have children and it can't have a closing tag, either.

If you want to put one image "on top" of another, replace the original image with a `div` of the same size, and put both images inside it. You can then absolutely position the second image on top of the first. Here's a modification to your function that will accomplish this:

```
function overlayImage(element, src, alt) {
   var
      div = document.createElement('div'),
      img = new Image();
   element.parentElement.insertBefore(div, element); // add the div to the parent
   div.style.display = 'inline-block'; // make it behave like an image
   div.style.position = 'relative'; // for absolute position of children
   div.appendChild(element);
   img.src = src;
   img.alt = alt;
   img.style.position = 'absolute';
   img.style.right = 0;
   img.style.top = 0;
   div.appendChild(img);
}
```

There you go!

### [See A Live Demo at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/KR8qn/)

What this does is replace your solo `<img src="(base)">` tag with the following structure.

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;">
   <img src="(base)">
   <img src="(overlay)" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;">
</div>
```

Of course, if you have control over the page it's probably better to create a CSS style you can apply instead of manually styling each element. If you have control over the page and you want to do this for many images, you could also create the above structure ahead of time instead of having to tweak it after page load with javascript.

Comment: will this code help me to append the image for dynamically adding image elements

Comment: I don't know--will it? It should be able to. Have you clicked on the link in my post to see the demo at jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you want to use Javascript for this?

You could do it with CSS quite easily:

```
HTML: 
<img id="image-back" src="image1.jpg"/>
<img id="image-front" src="image2.jpg"/>

CSS:
#image-front{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

If the idea is to do some sort of onclick event (like replacing the two images) you can do it like this:

```
HTML:
<img id="image-front" src="201307251701.PNG" onclick="doStuff()"/>

JavaScript:
function doStuff(){
  window.alert("Stuff done!");
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. The second image is going to go to the top right of it's nearest positioned ancestor (anything that isn't `position:static`, such as `position:absolute` or `position:relative`). That is not even close to the OP's request to put it in the top right of the other image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` as a wrapper for both images. One covers the whole `div`, but the second image is at top right corner of that `div`, and these two images are siblings, not parent-child.

```js
function appendImage(element, src, alt) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = src;
  image.alt = alt;
  image.style.position = "absolute";
  image.style.right = 0;
  element.appendChild(image);
  return false;
}

document.getElementById("wrap").onclick = function() {
  appendImage(this, 'http://placekitten.com/40/40', 'Picture of foo');
};
```

```css
#wrap {
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
Click on the kitty!
<div id="wrap">
  <img border="1" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,it is working for single image,but if i want to add this dynamically for multiple images means what shall i do?

Comment: @Sadhana: You should change it's position (position of new appended image) like this `image.style.right=30` and `image.style.top=50`

Comment: One problem with using a span as the enclosing element is that it doesn't expand to contain its children. Give your span a border to see what I'm talking about. This could cause problems in complex layouts. The element should at minimum be styled with `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append an image to another image. Use a html structure like this:

```
<div id="container"
     style="position: relative; width: 70px; height:70px"
     onclick="appendImage(this, 'cancel3.png', 'Picture of foo')">

     <img border="0" src="www.gravatar.com/avatar/" alt="" />

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript? I assume your image id is `myImage`.

```
var img = document.getElementById(myImage).style;
img.position = "absolute";
img.top = "0px";
img.right = "0px";
```